# How to get JQUERY Datatables content to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a jquery datatable which has not pre defined columns. I want to post datatable content to MVC Controller for checking values. I found [Datatables.api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()) for getting content and found something for serializing.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();


        var _content = table
            .rows()
            .data();    

       var _tableContent =JSON.stringify(_content, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(_content));
var url = "/Home/TestList";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                data:_tableContent
            },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
```

I can get data in Controller but i can not serialize

```
public class ColumnEntityList
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string[] _list { get; set; }
    }

 public ActionResult TestList(string data)
        {
             List<ColumnEntityList> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ColumnEntityList>>(data);
            return Json("temp");
        }
```

I need help about this issue..

{"0":["sadad","asdad","asdad","dsad","ewewasd"],
"1":["asdad","adsad","adsad","asdasd","adasdasd"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with sending params without json.

```
var _tableContent = new Array();
for (var i=0 ; i < _content.length ; i++) {
                _tableContent [i] = data[i];
            }
```

I can handle table content in Controller

```
public ActionResult TestList(string[][] data)
```

Comment: Do you mean _tableContent[i]  = _content[i] instead of data[i]? And how did you parse the data in controller? How come I am getting something like this in controller: "string[0][ ] ?